# Pass data through multiple components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

i am quite new to Reactjs. I try to pass my fetched data from an api through multiple components. Therefore i created three components:

```
const App = () =>  {
  const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState([]);
  const pokemon_number = 151;
  

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=${pokemon_number}`)
      .then(function (response) {
        const { data } = response;
        const { results } = data;
        const newPokemonData = [];
        results.forEach((pokemon, index) => {
          newPokemonData[index + 1] = {
            id: index + 1,
            name: pokemon.name,
            sprite: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${
              index + 1
            }.png`
          };
        });
        setPokemonData(newPokemonData);
      });
  }, []);
 
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <h2>All Pokémon:</h2>
    {console.log(pokemonData)}
    <PokemonList pokemonData={pokemonData} />
    
  </div>
)};


const PokemonList = ({pokemonData}) => {

  return (
    <div className='Pokemon_Container'>
    <PokemonCard pokemonDetails={pokemonData} />
    {console.log(pokemonData)}
    
    {pokemonData.map(pokemon => (<div key={pokemon.id}>{pokemon.name}
    <img src={pokemon.sprite} alt={pokemon.name} /> {pokemon.id}</div> ))
   ` }
    </div>
  )
}

const PokemonCard = ({pokemonDetails}) => {
    
  return (
    <div>{console.log(pokemonDetails[1].name)}</div>
  )
}
```

I fetched the pokemon from the api in App.js to give it to PokemonList which works fine and correctly. Now i am trying to call PokemonCard.js with the given data in PokemonList but it always fails to access the data with console.log when i try to call a specific attribute (for example pokemonDetails[1].name. pokemonDetails[1] works fine. Can you help me?

I just hope to pass the fetched data from the api call through multiple components. I'm stuck at the moment.

Comment: At first `pokemonDetails` is an empty array, so `pokemonDetails[1]` is `undefined` which will result in error trying to read `name` on it (`pokemonDetails[1].name`). Just do this `pokemonDetails?.[1].name`

Comment: Still the same error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')". Every function is a seperate .js file to clarify the factual situation

Comment: What @Bqardi wanted to write is `pokemonDetails[1]?.name`. The `?.` is called the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Sorry, you are right @GabrielePetrioli, thank you for the correct syntax.

Comment: So after this adjustment the Output will be the correct Pokémon Name? Can you explain why i cant follow around sorry haha